# Creating time schedules using available and nonavailable times stored in a dictionary

Tags: python, list, performance, dictionary

I have a list of entities for each of which there are available and nonavailable times stored in multiple lists. It is important to note that nonavailable times dominates the available  times. For example, suppose an entity is available between [1,5], [8,15] and is non-available between [2,4], [7, 9], and [11,13]. Then, I can use this entity in [1,2], [4,5], [9,11], and [13, 15]. As a MWE, I am giving a single entity.

```
time_dict = {
    'available': [[7590, 8280], [9030, 9720], [10470, 11160], [11910, 12600], [20550, 21240], [21990, 22680], [23430, 24120], [24870, 25560], [26310, 27000], [33510, 34200], [34950, 35640], [36390, 37080], [37830, 38520], [39270, 39960]],
    'not_available': [[7740, 7755], [7920, 7950], [8100, 8115], [9180, 9195], [9360, 9390], [9540, 9555], [10620, 10635], [10800, 10830], [10980, 10995], [12060, 12075], [12240, 12270], [12420, 12435], [20700, 20715], [20880, 20910], [21060, 21075], [22140, 22155], [22320, 22350], [22500, 22515], [23580, 23595], [23760, 23790], [23940, 23955], [25020, 25035], [25200, 25230], [25380, 25395], [26460, 26475], [26640, 26670], [26820, 26835], [33660, 33675], [33840, 33870], [34020, 34035], [35100, 35115], [35280, 35310], [35460, 35475], [36540, 36555], [36720, 36750], [36900, 36915], [37980, 37995], [38160, 38190], [38340, 38355], [39420, 39435], [39600, 39630], [39780, 39795]]
}
```

Now, I create available slots using a for loop.

```
available_slots = []

for available in time_dict['available']:
    start, end = available
    not_available = [d for d in time_dict['not_available'] if d[0] < end and d[1] > start]

    if not not_available:
        available_slots.append(available)
    else:
        prev_end = start
        for i in not_available:
            if i[0] > prev_end:
                available_slots.append([prev_end, i[0]])
            prev_end = i[1]
        if prev_end < end:
            available_slots.append([prev_end, end])

print("Available Slots:", available_slots)
Available Slots: [[7590, 7740], [7755, 7920], [7950, 8100], [8115, 8280], [9030, 9180], [9195, 9360], [9390, 9540], [9555, 9720], [10470, 10620], [10635, 10800], [10830, 10980], [10995, 11160], [11910, 12060], [12075, 12240], [12270, 12420], [12435, 12600], [20550, 20700], [20715, 20880], [20910, 21060], [21075, 21240], [21990, 22140], [22155, 22320], [22350, 22500], [22515, 22680], [23430, 23580], [23595, 23760], [23790, 23940], [23955, 24120], [24870, 25020], [25035, 25200], [25230, 25380], [25395, 25560], [26310, 26460], [26475, 26640], [26670, 26820], [26835, 27000], [33510, 33660], [33675, 33840], [33870, 34020], [34035, 34200], [34950, 35100], [35115, 35280], [35310, 35460], [35475, 35640], [36390, 36540], [36555, 36720], [36750, 36900], [36915, 37080], [37830, 37980], [37995, 38160], [38190, 38340], [38355, 38520], [39270, 39420], [39435, 39600], [39630, 39780], [39795, 39960]]
```

This works for me, but I don't find this effective. Since I will repeat this for each key in `time_dict`, I'll have a nested for loop. Is there a better way to conduct this operation?

Answer (score 0):

You could concatenate all timestamps into single list and add state annotations to them, then sort both based on timestamps.

Using your example

```
1 -> AVAILABLE_START (state 0), 
2 -> NOT_AVAILABLE_START (state 1), 
4 -> NOT_AVAILABLE_END (state 2), 
5 -> AVAILABLE_END (state 3), 
7 -> NOT_AVAILABLE_START
etc.
```

Write single for loop through all those states and switch logic based on those states.

```
for (current_timestamp, state) in zip(sorted_timestamps, sorted_states):

    if state == AVAILABLE_START:
        isAvailable = true
        if not isBlocked:
            slot_start = current_timestamp
    elif state == NOT_AVAILABLE_START:
        isBlocked = true
        if isAvailable:
            slot_end = current_timestamp
            slots.append(slot_start, slot_end)
    ...
```

Make sure your tests work, it may be tricky to address all edge cases